# Can I change the /blog/ slug to somthing elase in Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: wordpress

I have an issue with the /blog/ slug of my URLS of wordpress multisites. Can I change this slug to something else?

Comment: You should be able to do that with the `Settings -> Permalinks` option.

Answer (score 1):

First Method : ( Might fail with buddypress )

At site `Settings -> Permalinks -> Common Setting -> Default` ( Must select default only and don't touch any thing, If you need to change category base, tag base set at Network Admin only )

```
Network Admin -> Sites -> (root site) Permalink Sturcture -> /%category%/%post_id%
```

you can also try only `%post_id%`.

Second Method :

Go to `http://domain.com/wp-admin/options.php -> permalink_structure`

Default value should be `/blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`

Change the value manually to whatever.

```
/whatever/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/
```

or

```
 /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/
```

Visit `http://domain.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` but this time **DO NOT** save changes in order to flush the rewrite rules.  ( If you will save it will default again )

One of the methods should work, depending on your WP version. also - there are other ways to do it with rewrite rules and code - but I think that it is better ( and safer ) to use those stated above first ..)